# Looking for BeanShell Validator plugin for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, beanshell

I have inherited a Java WebApp that contains the majority of its business logic in a 16K line BeanShell File.

I am looking for something that will validate my BeanShell files so I know at least it is working as it should, if I could debug the script even better.

Any help to a tired and frustrated developer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There's http://eclipse-shell.sourceforge.net/. Though I haven't been able to get this to work (using Eclipse 3.4.2).

I'd love to find a BeanShell plugin for Eclipse.

Comment: the eclipse shell project is completely worthless, at least I don't have to deal with this project anymore.